# Ubuntu booting error: ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110

Tags: 14.04, boot

I hope I post in the right place.

Whenever I boot Ubuntu 14, I get this error:

```
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
hub 1-0:1.0: Cannot enable port 1. Maybe the USB cable is bad
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
ehci-pci 0000:00:id.0: port 1 reset error -110
```

Basically, the first error repeats like 10 times, with the other one "the one with " in the middle. The system boots fine, but I'm worried that it might crash one day and it's an office computer.

The only USB ports I use are for the mouse and a cooler under the laptop. I unplugged both of them before starting the laptop and I get the same error, yet the USB slots are empty.

The laptop is Acer Aspire E 15 Start. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For USB in Linux there are 3 'generic' drivers.

```
UHCI - USB 1.x (Universal Host Controller Interface)
EHCI - USB 2.x (Enhanced Host Controller Interface)
XHCI - USB 3.x (eXtensible Host Controller Interface)
```

The newer should be always compatible to the previous one.

The [Acer Website](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/series/aspire-e) shows there is a USB3.1 Port, but the Kernel thinks it is EHCI.

Solution 1:
Go to the BIOS and check if there is something like a 'Compatible mode' for the USB. I won't degrade the Port to 2.x, because 3.x got a plenty of cool features.

Solution 2:
Try to find the related rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and change it from ehci to xhci.
I would start with `grep -i ehci /etc/udev/rules.d/*` and `lsusb` to find the needed ID.

I don't think it is a hardware issue, or your laptop will suffer in any way from the message.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a hp14 laptop.  It is finally solved by going to BIOS and change the setting "USB3.0 Configuration in Pre-OS" from "Auto" to "Enable".  I have no clue why this solves the problem.